# Корректное выделение памяти динамическому массиву

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть тестовый класс

```
public class TestClass {
    private int[] arr;

    public TestClass(){}

    public void CreateArr(int size)
    {
        arr=new int[size];
    }

    public int[] getTest(){return arr;}

}
```

в Main я вызываю его

```
TestClass test=new TestClass();
int[] arr;

test.CreateArr(2);
arr=test.getTest();
test.CreateArr(5);
arr=test.getTest();
```

И у меня возник следующий вопрос, каждый раз при вызове CreateArr у нас происходит выделение памяти для массива `int[] arr` через new в классе `TestClass`, не будет ли это чревато утечками памяти, особенно если CreateArr будет вызываться в основном приложении очень часто?

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивают штатный классы Java (ArrayList и т.д.)? Зачем весь это велосипед?

Comment: ну например у нас есть OutputStream с методом write(byte[] b), если бы был метод write(ArrayList<T> b) я бы с удовольствием мог воспользоваться им, во-вторых мне хочется понять как будет выделяться память в данном случае и как будет работать сборщик мусора в данной ситуации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В java не нужно заботиться об освобождении памяти. Этим занимается GC. 
Но иногда могут возникнуть утечки памяти. Это возникает когда ссылка на объект который уже не используется хранится и доступна через другие объекты. В таких случаях, GC не может освободить память занимаемую этим объектом.
Что касается вашего случая, то создания массива в объекте нормальная практика и это не сулит никаких утечек.